# Finding outputs of the given inputs by using transform techniques

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I have following [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhARn.jpg) and I tried  to find Fourier Transform of the given inputs and impulse response.However I couldn't convert them to time domain after multiplication with fourier transform of impulse response.Can you help me how to find out the answers of the fourier transforms.Secondly , Did I think mistakenly to take Fourier Transform ?Should I have taken Laplace Transform ?You can find my solution here [my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFVBC.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to recognize what kind of system is described by the impulse response $h(t)$ (hint: it's an ideal filter), and to figure out the frequency content (by inspection) of the given input signals. It will turn out that some of them will not at all be modified by the system because their spectrum lies within the system's pass band, whereas others will not make it through the system at all because they only have frequency components in the system's stop band.